# Adding a KeyValuePair to the front of a Dictionary

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, collections

I have a dictionary that stores data for a dropdown and I want to add an all option but I want this to be the first entry in the collection so it will be in the correct order when I build my HTML.

The obvious solution would be to add the All option to a new dictionary and then loop through the items:

```
Dim ListWithALL As Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
ListWithALL.Add(0, "All")
For Each option As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String) In OptionsList
    ListWithALL.add(option)
Next
OptionsList = ListWithALL
ListWithALL.dispose()
```

But I don't really like this solution as it seems a bit of a long way and a performance hog.

I've also thought of using something like IComparable to and sorting the data but I don't want the other data to be in the same order in which they were added.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Well this is VB.Net code but you've tagged the question as C#. So what one are you using?!

Comment: It's not a language specific question it's a .NET framework question so can be answered by a C# dev or VB dev.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add an item to any "position" in a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`, as it is not sorted.

Use `SortedDictionary<Tkey,TValue>` if you need to ensure order - it is sorted by key order, so if you wish to place an item at the start, you need to use a key that will sort to the very start.

Comment: The thing with this is that I don't want to sort the other data in the dictionary as this is already in the order that I want it.  Thanks for bringing SortedDictionary to my attention though I can definitely use this at some point.

Comment: @NathanHastings - The only other option I can see is to add this item _first_ then all other items. However, how items are actually stored in a `Dictionary` is an implementation detail - it _might_ work, but might not. Consider an alternative design for fetching items from your dictionary.

Comment: Yeh I think your right regarding a alternative design, the reason I wanted it to be first is so I didn't have to duplicate code before my loop, but I'll come up with something.